# Swift Array, TextFile?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, textreader

I have a tableview that displays the following navigation from one tableview to another:

- Chapter 1

  - Topic 1

    - Heading 1

      - Sub Heading 1

        - Content 1

This is done using the following code:

```
 if var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt"){
         var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
         if var content = (data){

             //Breaks the entire String into individual strings at each newLine
             var line: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

             //First Table - Displays Chapters
             var lineArray = [line[0],
                              line[6],
                              line[12]]
```

How can I get it to read this instead?

Topics: Food, color, animals, cars `//each as a separate string.` 
If I use this, it will display the whole line as a text starting from "Topics: ...." so basically what I'm asking is, is there a way to read past Topics, and just Start the first string[0] at Food?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Is it an option to use a property list rather than a text file? A property list can consider multiple types like strings, numbers, arrays and dictionaries

Comment: @vadian It's just an option, something i'm looking into trying out and understanding how it works.

Comment: @ThomasKilian is it possible to break down a String into more strings. e.g. `"Topics: Food, Water, Melon, Car"` can it be broken in to `"Topics:","Food","water"` etc

Comment: @Bhavin yes :) would it be casting an array within an array

Comment: Its one of the lines in the Text file. which has been made a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know I'm understand your question or not but I think you want to skip `topics:` from string `Topics: Food, Water, Melon, Car`....So after separate the string you want Food at index 0...

```
  var str = "Topics: Food, color, animals, cars"

  // Get location of first Space or any character you want
  let loc = find(str, " ")

  //Get the string from first space to end of string     
  let skipstr = Range(start: loc!,
            end: str.endIndex)
  let finalStr = str.substringWithRange(skipstr)

  println(finalStr)  
  //Output:-->  Food, color, animals, cars
```

And then just separate string from comma

```
 let indexes = finalStr.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
 println(indexes[0])
 //And you got Food at index 0
```